# Back animation transition strange in UINavigationController?

Tags: objective-c

I got one Problem in my iphone app. I m developing UISlitViewcontroller with multiple detailview controller. All works well but one of my detailviewcontroller want to push more viewcontroller on particular detailview. Pusp and pop works well. while push the transition animation works well but while pop the transition not works.. Here is my code below.. Please tell solution for my problem.

//In app delegate i initialize my splitviewcontroller...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.rootVC = [[MasterViewController1 alloc]init];
    self.detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *DetailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.detailVC];

    SplitVC = [[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
    SplitVC.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.rootVC, DetailNav, nil];
    SplitVC.delegate = self.detailVC;

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = SplitVC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

//In Master view I use mutiple viewcontroller like this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    [self.appDelegate.SplitVC viewWillDisappear:YES];
    NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self.appDelegate.SplitVC.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers]];
    [viewControllerArray removeLastObject];


    if (row == 0) 
    {
        self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.detailViewController];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = self.detailViewController;
        self.appDelegate.SplitVC.delegate = self.detailViewController;
    }
    if (row == 1) 
    {
        self.currencyVC = [[CurrencyConvertorViewController alloc]init];
        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.currencyVC];
        self.currencyVC.detailItem = self.currencyVC;
        self.appDelegate.SplitVC.delegate = self.currencyVC;
    }

    if (row == 2) 
    {
        self.latest = [[PhoneExample alloc]init];
        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.latest];
        self.latest.detailItem = self.latest;
        self.appDelegate.SplitVC.delegate = self.latest;
    }

    if (row == 3) 
    {
        self.settingsVC = [[SettingPage alloc]init];
        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.settingsVC];
        self.settingsVC.detailItem = self.settingsVC;
        self.appDelegate.SplitVC.delegate = self.settingsVC;
    }
    [[self.appDelegate.SplitVC.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setViewControllers:viewControllerArray animated:NO];    
    [self.appDelegate.SplitVC viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

In one of my Detail view controller I pushing anotherview controller in same Master selected row Viewcontroller like this

-

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LatestVersionMobileViewController *phone_version = [[LatestVersionMobileViewController alloc]init];
    phone_version.phone = [phone_types objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.title = @"Phones";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:phone_version animated:YES];
}
```

Then UserOrientation like this..

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
    {
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];

 CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 768);
        self.view.frame = frame1;
        frame1.size.width = frame1.size.width + 10;
        myTable.frame = frame1;
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }
    else 
    {
        [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:self.appDelegate.rootPopoverButtonItem];

        frame.origin.x = 0;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        self.view.frame = frame;
        myTable.frame = frame;
        return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
```

}